# next-redux-wrapper server not sync with client?

Tags: redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

Currently to do Next js and Redux connect with `next-redux-wrapper`.

The problem is the code does not work as I think..

I'm trying to make basic counter

What I expected

During `getServerSideProps`, dispatch add(3) that add 3 to initialState 0,

so after SSR, expected initial value is 3

but it is 0 actually.

Here is my code

`Index.tsx`

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
    (store) => async () => {
        store.dispatch(add(3));
        return {
            props: {},
        };
    }
);
const index = (props: any) => {
    const count = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.counter.count);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (
        <>
            <div>{count}</div>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(add(1))}>+</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(deleter(2))}>-</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

`store.ts`

```
export const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'counter',
    initialState: { count: 0 },
    reducers: {
        add: (state, action) => {
            state.count += action.payload;
        },
        deleter: (state, action) => {
            state.count -= action.payload;
        },
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [HYDRATE]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('HYDRATE', state, action.payload);
            const nextState = { ...state, ...action.payload };
            return { ...nextState };
        },
    },
});
const makeStore = () =>
    configureStore({
        reducer: {
            [counterSlice.name]: counterSlice.reducer,
        },
        devTools: true,
    });

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export const wrapper = createWrapper<AppStore>(makeStore);
```

I've deleted that looks unneccessary(Some Types...) and

in `_app.tsx`, I did wrap the app component with WithRedux.

Is there anything I think incorrectly??

Answer (score 1):

I found why....

The Hydrate part should be

```
extraReducers: {
        [HYDRATE]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('HYDRATE', state, action.payload);
            const nextState = { ...state, ...action.payload.counter };

            return nextState;
        },
    },
```